# Combining multiple Worksheet_Change macros

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to combine multiple worksheet_change macros (see code below).  My goal is that whenever the "target" range (a merged, drop-down list cell) is changed, the ranges below (again, merged cells) will clear.  I need to do this for when MULTIPLE different cells are changed, hence the multiple worksheet change codes.

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J1:O1")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J2:O3").ClearContents
        Range("D15:E15").ClearContents
            Range("B16:E16").ClearContents
                Range("B17:E19").ClearContents
        Range("D20:E20").ClearContents
            Range("B21:E21").ClearContents
                Range("B22:E24").ClearContents
        Range("D25:E25").ClearContents
            Range("B26:E26").ClearContents
                 Range("B27:E29").ClearContents
        Range("D30:E30").ClearContents
            Range("B31:E31").ClearContents
                 Range("B32:E34").ClearContents
        Range("B3:H14").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("J2:K2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J3:K3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("L2:M2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("L3:M3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub

    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Range("N2:O2")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("N3:O3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have all those subs in a single worksheet module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below is simply your code put together in 1 `Sub` with multiple `If statements`. The only change is that the `If` is now an `If Not` which will process the code if there is an `Intersect` and then `Exit sub`.

The following code will do the trick:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J1:O1")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J2:O3").ClearContents
        Range("D15:E15").ClearContents
        Range("B16:E16").ClearContents
        Range("B17:E19").ClearContents
        Range("D20:E20").ClearContents
        Range("B21:E21").ClearContents
        Range("B22:E24").ClearContents
        Range("D25:E25").ClearContents
        Range("B26:E26").ClearContents
        Range("B27:E29").ClearContents
        Range("D30:E30").ClearContents
        Range("B31:E31").ClearContents
        Range("B32:E34").ClearContents
        Range("B3:H14").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J2:K2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J3:K3").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2:M2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("L3:M3").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N2:O2")) Is Nothing Then
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("N3:O3").ClearContents
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Exit Sub
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J1:O1")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J2:O3").ClearContents
        Range("D15:E15").ClearContents
            Range("B16:E16").ClearContents
                Range("B17:E19").ClearContents
        Range("D20:E20").ClearContents
            Range("B21:E21").ClearContents
                Range("B22:E24").ClearContents
        Range("D25:E25").ClearContents
            Range("B26:E26").ClearContents
                 Range("B27:E29").ClearContents
        Range("D30:E30").ClearContents
            Range("B31:E31").ClearContents
                 Range("B32:E34").ClearContents
        Range("B3:H14").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J2:K2")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("J3:K3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2:M2")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("L3:M3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("N2:O2")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Range("N3:O3").ClearContents
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```